# web2py: how to enable "request_reset_password" function?

Tags: python, frameworks, web2py

I'm new to web2py but eager to learn it fast.
I try to enable "request_reset_passwor" function but every time I enter this page:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/default/user/request_reset_password
```

I receive message that the function is disabled.

Can you please tell me what should I do and  where to get it working?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set up your mail server in db.py first...